# How to add grid that enable diagonal scroll in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I want to add grid that enable diagonal scroll(horizontal and vertical at the same time) in flutter
Temporarily I programmed using overwrapped SingleChildScrollView that Inner is Axis.horizontal, Outer is Axis.vertical

**my code**:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xff18171C),
            body: StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (context, setState) {
                return Stack(
                  children: [
                    LayoutBuilder(
                      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                        return SizedBox(
                            height: constraints.maxHeight - 0.05,
                            child:
                            //============================================================================
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              child: Center(
                                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                    child: SettingGrid(row, column),
                                  )),
                            ));
                        //================================================================================
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
        ));
  }

  Widget SettingGrid(int row, int column) {
    var index = 0;
    Widget widget;
    List<Widget> temp = [];
    List<Widget> temp2 = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
      temp = [];
      for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {

        switch(edit_seats_mode)
        {
          case Edit_Seats_Mode.RowOrColumn:
            widget = used_seatbutton(row: j, column: i, myindex: index, SetState: SetState,);
            temp.add(widget);

            index++;
            break;
          case Edit_Seats_Mode.UsedOrUnused:
            if(unused_seats_index.contains(index))//if seats exist
              {
              widget = unused_seatbutton(row: j, column: i, myindex: index, SetState: SetState,);
            }
            else
            {
              widget = used_seatbutton(row: j, column: i, myindex: index, SetState: SetState,);
            }
            temp.add(widget);
            index++;
            break;
        }
      }
      temp2.add(Row(children: temp));
    }

    return Column(
      children: temp2,
    );
  }
```

**my rsult**:
[image]

As you can see, It can scroll only horizontal and vertical, not diagonal

thanks for reading

Comment: why not using `InteractiveViewer`?

Comment: I didn't know 'InteractiveViewer' class thanks